# fixed divs inside container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok the deal is I have a page with a top banner 100% wide and 500px tall and below that a content area, say, 4000px tall. inside that content area there is a box (100 by 100) that I want to have act the way in a certain way. When I scroll down the page to the point were that box touches the top of the screen I want it to be fixed at the top until I scroll up and it becomes unfixed at the top of the parent container (so where it was to start). Anyone have any examples or simple fixes????

Edit:

I found this fix that I think will work but I don't know what I am doing wrong:

```
    <script>

    var $window = $(window),
    $sticky = $('#contentSideIner'),
    elTop = $sticky.offset().top;

    $window.scroll(function() {
    $sticky.toggleClass('sticky', $window.scrollTop() > elTop);
    });

    </script>
```

(code is in the head of the html document)

```
#contentSide {
background: black;
margin: 10px;
float: right;
width: 300px;
}
#contentSideIner {
width: 280px;
height: 400px;
margin: 0 auto;
background: red;
}

.sticky {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
}
```

I know this code is meant to add a class to the #contentSideIner div, .sticky {position: fixed; top: 0; }. am I making a kind of brain dead mistake here?

this is the jfiddel that is basicly what i have http://jsfiddle.net/07xe5tLf/

more code i have in use:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Project Website: full review pages</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />


    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    var $window = $(window),
    $sticky = $('#contentSideIner'),
    elTop = $sticky.offset().top;

    $window.scroll(function() {
    $sticky.toggleClass('sticky', $window.scrollTop() > elTop);
    });

    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesMainReveiw.css" />

    <style>
        #banner { background-image: url("images/Destiny_Banner.jpg"); }
        .playableOn {}
        .rateBox { background-image: url("img/rating/rating3-big.png");  background-size: 150px 150px; }
        #contentSide { height: 5100px; }
    </style>

</head>
<body class="landing">

    <!-- Header -->
        <header id="header">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Monthly Spotlight</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="reviewDestiny.html">Destiny</a></li>
                        <li><a href="reviewDiablo.html">Diablo III</a></li>
                        <li><a href="reviewShadow.html">Shadow Of Mordor</a></li>
                        <li><a href="reviewTheLastOfUs.html">The Last Of Us</a>
                        <li><a href="reviewBayonetta.html">Bayonetta 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Older Reviews</a></li>
            </ul>
        </header>

    <!-- Banner -->
        <section id="banner">
            <h1>destiny</h1>
            <h2>"Same Quote for the game as seen in js-load"</h2>
                <div class="playableOn"><p>Playable On:</p></div>
                <div class="rateBox"></div>
        </section>

    <!-- Main -->
        <section id="main" class="container">
            <div id="contentSide">
                <div id="contentSideIner">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please see the help center on how to ask questions: "Questions asking for (homework) help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it". I don't think you're in the right place if you're looking for someone to write your code for you.

Comment: No you completely misunderstand, 1.) i dont fell that this site allows me to post hundreds of lines a code that has nothing to do with the issue i am having 2.) this is a good resource i just dont know the fastest easyest and best way to get this effect.

Comment: the question is very simple, i just don't know what to look for in fixing divs based on page scrolling

Comment: The problem is you're asking a question that is incomplete and does not follow the quality standards this community requires.  If you're not willing to attempt to solve the problem first and then after that ask a clear, concise question that follows the community guidelines, then don't expect help from the community.

Comment: On your edit: are you including jQuery?

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` (this is using [Googles hosted libraries](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide))

Comment: If you need a place to easily work and share your code, use [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) (Quick, for small things) or [Cloud9](http://c9.io) (for entire projects)

Comment: that ajax link didn't work, but i posted a jfiddle that is a good mock-up of what i have right now.

Comment: A note to other people: please don't flag this because it contains good information about the nature of StackOverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is what it seems you want](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-sticky-position/)

What you want is a sticky menu which requires javascript to find the current position of the page in the viewport and change the CSS or class to make it fixed. This is a bad example because there is no div that is made visible after you scroll and make the element fixed to prevent the page content below to fill in where the menubar was. This can be done simply by using jQuery to make this hidden div visible. If you need code then just ask.

It is called a sticky menu and I always forget what it is called. :)

How I remember is usually spending some time on Google searching specifically for what I want until I find it. Don't make StackOverflow your default goto for help because that is how you can get banned. You need to be specific and provide code on something like [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or spend some time making a visual example or find a site that does what you want. Many sites like Facebook use this technique and it is quite common. If this doesn't make sense then you should go to [W3Schools](http://w3schools.com) and read up on some Javascript and CSS and find some tutorials on [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

---

For your fiddle, you need to go and include jQuery in your head: http://jsfiddle.net/b2550/07xe5tLf/1/

I JSFiddle it is as simple as making that your framework in the sidebar and in your code you need to include this in your head (as I said above in the comments)

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am trying to use the edits i made to the original post now but it does not seam to be adding the class to any div. The #contentSideIner is inside #contentSide, contentSide is the placholder "track" for it to slide up an down in. And ya stackoverflow had been great and bad for me. i cant post big batches of code effectively here so i don't.

Comment: I just cant wrap my head around why asking for a plug-in or code concept is so frownd upon. like here my answer seams to be use some java script to add and remove a class to the div when it hits a point. to get that answer should not reqiure me to to post the whole page of html i am working on. that's the way i see it. most of my problems are just that, i need to set on the right track and that's all. like you did. code did not help you in adding me so it should not be necessary.

Comment: StackOverflow has evolved slowly to have very strict rules that people just have to follow. If you follow the format that most people expect you will get better results and unfortunately it makes it much harder to ask certain questions, especially if you don't know what you are looking for.

Comment: that i would site as a very big flaw of stackoverflow for people that are out to use it for the right reasons that need creative or plug-in like help. But when i look at it ya i can see that reasons why it is the way it is. I work for hours on the questions that i post but right now i feel like "stackoverflow, the only place you get nigitive rep for asking for help."

Comment: Well another thing that 4chan users like to say (not to say you should go on 4chan) is that "we are not your personal army" which means that people want to debug and edit your code, not create it. Most people would not spend the amount of time I have helping you and you just have to accept that. Believe me when I say that it used to be even worse. If you are having big issues the people over at StackExchange are pretty nice and will help you if you email them.

Comment: like i said, i see the good reasons. i just thought this was going to be a ton simpler. but i have now edited my post to have a good description and code that i am trying to use.

Comment: and vote ups are always appreciated if you feed I helped you.

Comment: certainly i do feel that way, but its not working. 1 i cant find what you did you the jfiddle to make it work. 2 the ajax is in my head and its not working.

Comment: In the sidebar on the right there is a dropdown where you can include various javascript libraries/apis/frameworks that allow you to do various things. jQuery is a very popularly used framework that adds more functions to javascript. As for your code, you need to include jQuery (the script reference I gave to you) and you have to have your actual script in the head as well. If you are new to jQuery I highly recommend taking a look at it.

Comment: i have copyed my whole head and everything down to the div in question in the into my main post